# Кто может привести КЛАССНУЮ аналогию работы 7-миуровневой модели OSI?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, osi

Привет.

Кто может привести **хорошую** аналогию (из жизни) эталонной модели взаимосвязи открытых систем (Open System Interconnection, OSI)? Чтобы эта аналогия **полностью** отражала работу OSI от прикладного уровня до физического. Когда открываешь любую книгу, то описано все как-то запутано. Как буд-то специально запутано пишут. И после прочтения больше вопросов, чем было до того, как книгу открываешь. То есть, переложить "сухую" (непонятную, абстрактную) книжную модель OSI на что-то (аналогия) из реальной жизни.

Хочу **понять** модель OSI, а не тупо заучивать, как стих. Понять, как задумывалась эта модель.

Понимаю только то, что модель придумали для того, чтобы разбить сложную задачу (например, ввожу в браузере юрл сайта и захожу на него) на более простые куски. Так легче разработать и легче ошибку словить. На каждом из уровней есть свои "правила" обработки поступившей (с уровня выше или уровня ниже) - протоколы.

Не могу в голове получить целостную картину работы модели OSI. Например, ввожу я в браузере "http://google.ru", жму энтэр, данные поехали на прикладной уровень , с ними происходит  то-то..... В самом конце - на выходе из сетевой карты получил серию импульсов-бит. Хочу разобраться в подробностях.

Какие есть программы, которые позволяют "пощупать" руками обмен данными между клиентом и сервером? Чтобы можно было передаваемые куски данных "потрогать" руками.

Comment: Я, например, не могу.

Comment: я тоже не могу. лучшая аналогия, которую я нашел - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKbiYFftp84

Comment: Если биологические науки вам близки, то грубо говоря, экология изучает популяции, морфология - организмы, гистология - ткани, цитология - клетки, далее молекулярная биология, а там и до строения атома недалеко :) То есть экологии неважно, как устроен отдельный организм, далее аналогично.

Comment: вопрос не решен, а кто-то уже предлагает закрыть его. прикол)

Comment: @Dimon: Может быть, это потому, что ваш вопрос — оффтопик?

Comment: тогда к какой теме принадлежит вопрос?

Comment: @VladD, вопрос закроют, поскольку он слишком обширен (а жаль, целиком все писать лень (поскольку на  каждом шаге придется лезть в кучу если не RFC, то статей в вике), а вот обсудить какие-то вещи  в комментах/чате было бы здорово).

Comment: Я не вижу смысла приводить аналогию. Её можно понять "как есть", сверху (с прикладного уровня) вниз, разбором уровней по одному. Потому что на каждом уровне можно сидеть, более-менее забыв об уровнях ниже, они работают себе и работают, а мы видим только результаты. Большую часть времени. А остальные случаи можно рассмотреть, уже спускаясь.

Comment: @all: Раз на вопрос уже дан хороший ответ, имеет смысл переоткрыть его.

Comment: *"Какие есть программы, которые позволяют "пощупать" руками обмен данными между клиентом и сервером? Чтобы можно было передаваемые куски данных "потрогать" руками."* - вот это сразу не заметил, вам нужен wireshark, конечно. Он без проблем покажет вложенные друг в друга пакеты.

Answer (score 6):

Боб, статный и красивый юноша, приходит в компанию по исполнению желаний и доставке всячестей в русском квартале Бруклина, кладет ноги на стол и требует, чтобы некоей "Алисе из Санкт-Петербурга" непременно передали сообщение, которое он тут же и диктует менеджеру компании. Сообщение умещается на двух сотнях листов А4, после чего менеджер клянется, что все будет доставлено и уходит в соседнюю комнату передавать послание.

Это - уровень приложения, на котором пользователь использует интерфейс, позволяющий передать ему данные в сервис. Помимо прямого контакта с менеджером Боб мог позвонить в компанию или сам подготовить двести листов А4.

После этого менеджер спускает заявку в отдел оформления. В этом отделе специалисты берут рукописный текст, перепечатывают его, соблюдая все нормы форматирования, а сверху шлепают дополнительный листок бумаги, на котором пишут адрес транслитом, чтобы по пути из Америки в Россию любой почтальон мог хотя бы выговорить его вслух. После этого ответственный руководитель нежно встряхивает получившуюся стопку листов и относит ее вместе с другими в отдел доставки.

Это - presentation layer, пакующий разнородные данные пользователя в четкие структуры, которыми оперирует сервис.

Отдел доставки принимает увесистую кипу листов, в числе которых находится письмо Боба. Так как Алиса живет в другой стране, письмо должно соответствовать документам, определяющему передачу отправлений из американского филиала в российский филиал. Если такого документа нет, руководители отдела доставки начинают переписываться, используя нижеописанные протоколы, чтобы достичь консенсуса перед передачей реальных отправлений.

Это - сессионный уровень, который ответственен за установку связи между различными экземплярами сервисов приложения.

После того, как заключен договор на передачу отправлений, отдел доставки решает, как именно лучше всего доставлять листы, из которых состоят отправления. Чтобы не пересылать в случае потерь письмо Боба целиком, оно делится на несколько отдельных стопок листов, в начало каждой кладется еще один дополнительный лист, на котором написано кому (а/я 9042), от кого (а/я 65535), порядковый номер стопки и количество листов в стопке - таким образом получающая сторона сможет получать стопки листов в произвольном порядке и все равно собрать их в исходном порядке.

Это - транспортный уровень. За что он ответственен, писать не буду, чтобы не опозориться; думаю, в комментариях подскажут точнее.

Разделив письмо на отдельные стопки, отдел доставки передает их в почту, наказав передать в Санкт-Петербург. Почта добавляет сверху еще один лист, на котором написано "Из: Бруклин, В: Санкт-Петербург, Листов: N". Почта была бы рада проделать весь путь одним махом, но адреса доставки разделяет океан, и прямого сообщения нет.
Поэтому почта доставляет до следующего офиса в сторону Санкт-Петербурга. Почта знает, что этот офис передаст отправления на еще один узел ближе при первой же возможности, и рано или поздно отправления дойдут до океана, потом пересекут его, а в Санкт-Петербурге увидят совпадение конечного адреса и передадут со склада в отдел клиентской доставки, который уже и будет разбираться с а/я.

Это - сетевой уровень, который отвечает за взаимодействие узлов, как единого организма. Сетевой уровень ничего не знает о населении узлов, но может организовать доставку отправлений от одного узла к другому, чтобы узел сам разобрался, кому именно было отправлено отправление.

Доставку между отдельными офисами обеспечивают водители грузовиков. Водители грузовиков не знают точных адресов офисов в других странах, но знают точные адреса соседних офисов: например, что офис №1 находится на улице Стремянной. Кроме того, водители грузовиков знают протокол приемки-передачи отправлений и какие формы нужно заполнить.

Это - канальный уровень, обеспечивающий связь между отдельными узлами.

Остается только физический уровень: когда водитель доставляет стопки листов из пункта А в пункт Б, они физически переезжают из одного места в другое.

Когда стопки физически доплывут до России, их примет водитель грузовика.
Водитель грузовика перевезет их из порта в АСЦ "Санкт-Петербург".
АСЦ "Санкт-Петербург" разберется, что именно за адрес указан в отправлениях.
По этому адресу начнут поступать стопки листов, составляющие письма.
Как только письмо целиком соберется, оно поступит в отдел оформления.
Отдел оформления обратно транслитерирует адрес и передаст письмо ответственному чтецу.
Ответственный чтец с выражением и по принятой в компании схеме зачитает полученное письмо Алисе.

Получается следующая схема:

- Передаются произвольные пользовательские данные
- Для передачи данные преобразовываются в четко определенные структуры
- Для передачи структур организовывается соединение сервисов приложения
- Передаваемые внутри соединения данные оборачиваются в пакеты транспортного уровня для обеспечения требований передачи данных
- Пакеты транспортного уровня передаются по сети с указанием конечного адреса
- Каждый узел сети передает пакеты товарищу, расположенному ближе к конечному адресу
- На физическом уровне это конвертируется в изменение напряжения на коннекторах, в радиоволны или иной формат передачи данных

---

Я скорее всего порядком наврал, простите, если что. Не стесняйтесь редактировать, если видите факап.

Comment: Транспортный уровень отвечает за гарантированную доставку, а не за оформление.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. насколько мне известно, на presentation уровне адрес (ip, mac или порт) не "вешается". наверно, придется разобраться с тем, как работает КАЖДЫЙ из протоколов, чтобы понять, как эти модели (OIS и TCP/IP) работают.

Comment: @PavelMayorov UDP не отвечает за гаратированную доставку

Comment: @Dimon здесь не имелось в виду ничего такого. В реальном приложении на этом этапе подставлялся бы айдишник пользователя, а не адрес базы данных, куда должна уйти запись

Comment: @Etki: Мегакруто, вы спасли вопрос.

Comment: @Etki, просто здорово (и никаких RFC!)